# Fetch CoreData entity as per Model class and not create separate NSManaged subclass

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Let's say I have a model like below

```
class Employee: Codable {    
    var id: String?
    var personalDetails: Person?
}

class Person: Codable {
    var firstName:String?
    var lastName: String?
}
```

Now I have to maintain an *Entity*(say DBEmployee) inside *CoreData* which will have the exact same properties

Now, is there a way to **NOT** create a separate `NSManaged` subclass(DBEmployee) for that entity which will have the same properties(as Employee) and have that entity extract it's properties as per the properties of `Employee`

My main problem is when I create my CoreData operations for fetch, it returns me `DBEmployee` which *I then have to convert* to `Employee` which has exactly the same properties (because the method that uses this fetch accepts Employee as the parameter and not DBEmployee)

Comment: Think of it the other way around, try to make your core data class implement Codable instead and you wont need `Employee` (or rather you can rename DBEmployee)

Comment: Actually, converting is the best approach, since you probably want to pass around (and modify) your `Employee` and `Person` instances. `NSManagedObject` should not be passed between different threads, because it is not thread-safe. For example, `RxCoreData` library takes similar approach, requiring an initializer `init(entity: NSManagedObject)` to create a copy of CoreData entity and method `update(_ entity: NSManagedObject)` to perform synchronization (apply changes from the copy to CoreData entity).

Comment: The `NSManagedObject` subclass does not allow conformance to `Codable`

Comment: Core Data requires `NSManagedObject` classes representing the entities.  It’s not trivial to make them conforming to `Codable` but it’s possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can get values back as either a NSManaged object / subclass or a dictionary of [String:Any] depending on the fetch result type. However, neither of those is a POSO (plain old Swift object.)

Since they both have the exact same properties, can you can change the method / API to take a protocol instead?

It really comes down to if the API really needs a Codable model (because it’s going to serialize it, for example) or if you can change the method (or possibly add to it)